# Insert the current datetime automatically using redux form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="AddAssignmentForm">
      <div className="form-body">
        <div>
          <Field name="assignment" component={renderField} type="text" label="Assignment" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <Field name="github" component={renderField} type="text" label="Github" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <Field name="teacher" component={renderField} type="text" label="Teacher" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="button-class">
          <button
            type="submit"
            name="action"
            disabled={pristine || submitting || invalid}
            className="waves-effect waves-light btn"
          >
            Submit
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            disabled={pristine || submitting}
            onClick={reset}
            className="waves-effect waves-light btn"
          >
            Clear Values
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

I have this redux form.I want to input the datetime when an user fill up the form and store it somewhere. Does anyone knows what can be done?

Comment: Can you show you code?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the questions and put the code...

Comment: it's safer (and recommended) to do it on server side using backend language (php, node.js) or even sql query

Comment: As @xadm has said, try and record timestamps on your server rather than on the client. Client generated timestamps create all kinds of hurt ..

Comment: yes, I think so doing it in the server side is a good option but I want to learn the way of doing it using Redux Form...

Answer (score 0):

The function that gets executed when the user submit the form is the `onSubmit` on your redux form dispatch functions. So I would generate the timestamp there and do whatever you need with it.